# SVN HTTP Error edit-pipeline svndiff1 absent-entries commit-revprops depth log-revprops partial-replay

Tags: svn

I have a problem with mi SVN repository. I have this repository

```
 http://localhost:8080/repos/security/
```

and I don't have any problem to see my files. But suddenly, I can't see my files. Like the link wasn't right and have a network problem.
Then I did some research about SVN (because  I don't configure it) and use this command: 
svnserve -i 
And now when I use the link, I have this message:

```
 ( success ( 2 2 ( ) ( edit-pipeline svndiff1 absent-entries commit-revprops depth log-revprops partial-replay ) ) )
```

What Am I missing? What I need to do to see my files again using that link?
I'm using linux

Comment: You don't give any hint about how you expect to "see" your files. Shall we assume that you mean opening the URL in a regular web browser?

Comment: That's right... I open the URL in any browser, then I need to sign in (Login & Password) and then I can see my files in list

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid that [svnserve](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.serverconfig.svnserve.html) can't speak HTTP. This tool is:

> a lightweight server, capable of speaking to clients over TCP/IP using a **custom, stateful protocol**.  Clients contact an svnserve server by using **URLs that begin with the `svn://` or `svn+ssh://` scheme**.

You need to install and/or configure a **web server** with a module to understand Subversion repositories (WebDAV), typically [Apache](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.serverconfig.choosing.html#svn.serverconfig.choosing.apache). Check your distribution's package manager for the appropriate packages: I think you already have Apache but not the `mod_svn` module.

Comment: I did have Apache... And also can open my URL and everything was fine. I don't know what happen... I'm going to check Apache configuration